# Extending an object in a managed package (illuminated cloud)

Tags: illuminatedcloud

I have an object in a managed package that I would like to extend in my package by adding a simple number field to it. I add the field and retrieve the object via illuminated cloud but the full object definition comes back. I'd like to only retrieve the columns I've added. Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: @ScottWells provides great support for his product. I believe this to be a bug so you would want to log it here: https://bitbucket.org/RoseSilverSoftware/illuminatedcloud/issues. It could also be WAD since retrieving an objects metadata partially could be an issue if/when you try to deploy it back to the server causing fields to be deleted. Just a thought....

Comment: Chris, you should be able to do this by not selecting the full CustomObject and then selecting just the CustomField entries that you want in your metadata subscription.  You should get back the portion of the .object file that corresponds to exactly those fields.  If you have trouble with it, don't hesitate to let me know.